# Template instantiation parse error

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, c++17

Sorry for the vague title, I don't understand the problem well enough to even describe it properly. I just don't understand why the last line of my `main()` fails. A moderate amount of nested template calls follows:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct ObjFirst {};

template <typename T>
struct ObjFirst<void (*)(T)> {
  template <void (*fp)(T)>
  static void f(T arg){fp(arg);}
};

template <typename T, typename R>
struct ObjFirst<R (*)(T)> {
  template <R (*fp)(T)>
  static R f(T arg) {return fp(arg);}
};

template <typename T>
struct Id {
  template <T fn_ptr>
  static auto funcPtr(void) { return &ObjFirst<T>::template f<fn_ptr>; }
};

template <auto fn>
auto id() { return Id<decltype(fn)>::template funcPtr<fn>(); }

int sampleFunc(int) {return 0;}
void sampleFuncV(int) {}

template <typename R, typename T>
R sampleFuncT(T) {return R{};}

template <>
int sampleFuncT<int, int>(int i) {return 7+i;}

struct A {};
struct B : A {};

int main()
{
    id<&sampleFunc>(); // OK
    id<&sampleFuncV>(); // OK
    auto f = id<&sampleFuncT<int, int>>(); // OK
    std::cout << f(3); // Double-checking the result: OK ('10')

    id<&std::dynamic_cast<B, A>>();
    return 0;
}
```

You can see that a couple various calls of this template mechanism work, but the last one doesn't . For a moment I thought it's because the wrong `ObjFirst` specialization is selected for a templated argument, but nope.

Any ideas appreciated. The failure can be observed with GCC 7, GCC 8 and clang 6: https://godbolt.org/g/5spCJy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is based on the belief that `dynamic_cast` is specified in the standard as something like this:

```
namespace std {
    template <typename Dst, typename Src>
    Dst* dynamic_cast(Src* );
}
```

But while the four C++ casts may look like invocations of function templates, they're actually part of the core language. These are keywords, they're unscoped, and while they accept one thing that looks like a template type parameter, it's actually not.

So `&std::dynamic_cast<B, A>` doesn't make any sense. There's no `std::dynamic_cast` at all, `dynamic_cast` only takes one type argument, and you can't have a "partial" dynamic cast - the expression is `dynamic_cast<T>(v)`, you cannot just have `dynamic_cast<T>` by itself.

---

Assuming `std::dynamic_cast` is just a typo for `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`, there are two other problems with your code:

1. You cannot `dynamic_cast` an `A*` to a `B*`. You can *upcast* non-polymorphic objects/pointers, but you can't *downcast* them. So this is ill-formed.
2. If you make `A` polymorphic, the problem is would become more clear if you reduce it a little bit and make the base case of `ObjFirst` incomplete instead of empty:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   struct ObjFirst;

   template <typename T>
   struct ObjFirst<void (*)(T)> {}; 

   template <typename T, typename R>
   struct ObjFirst<R (*)(T)> {} ;

   struct B { };
   struct D : B { };

   int main()
   {
       ObjFirst<decltype(&std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B,D>)> n;
   }
   ```

This fails to compile with the error:

```
foo.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cxx:18:57: error: aggregate ‘ObjFirst<std::shared_ptr<B> (*)(const std::shared_ptr<D>&) noexcept> n’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
     ObjFirst<decltype(&std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B,D>)> n;
                                                         ^
```

Which should make it clear what the problem is. You have specializations for `void(*)(T)` and `R(*)(T)`, but [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) doesn't match either because `noexcept` is now part of the type system.

Comment: Ugh, did I really put `dynamic_cast` there? That's what I turn into after 8 hours of studying template errors. I meant `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`. Let me see if there's actually any error there after I fix the code...

Comment: Yep, fixed the code in the question, still getting the error (a different one, of course).

Comment: @VioletGiraffe You can't `dynamic_cast` from `A*` to `B*`, you'd have to go the other way (or make `A` polymorphic)

Comment: Fixed that, too.

Comment: Wow. I figured the base non-specialized template must be instantiating here (you demonstrated a very neat way of checking it, although I should have just put a `static_assert` inside), but I didn't understand why that is. Now I do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does that mean i must duplicate each specialization for `noexcept`, or is there a more generic workaround?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Nope. Gotta duplicate (can't deduce `noexcept`-ness)